# Moving the "cursor" back a line for stdout

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a little command line tool (written in Objective C, runs under MacOS) that tracks changes to folders and applies rules to files. This tool also informs the user about the progress. It says like:

```
"Found 3 files of type Z and applied rule"
"Found 6 files of typ x and applied rules"
```

Currently, the tool outputs the feedback as an endless list but this does not look very handy. What I'm after is a solution to only type the line per file type once and then update the number in the terminal if the tool finds another file of that type. Very similar to how "top" under Unix gives the feedback.

However, to do so, I'll need to move the cursor in the terminal backwards to the beginning of the line and also one or multiple lines backwards.

Is this possible and does anybody know, how to do so?

Thanks
Norbert

Comment: Research `ncurses`. This is how `top` and related tools do it. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ncurses.3x.html

Comment: That is what I have been looking for! Thanks!